# How to prompt users to select the worksheet and the range?

Tags: excel, vba

My question is how do I prompt the user to select the sheet and range from the same workbook but different worksheet?

```
Sub parse_data()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    'vsht = Application.InputBox("Type the name of the sheet", Type:=2)
    vcol = 1    #Filtering on this column
    vcol = Application.InputBox("Type in the Column No", Type:=1)
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
```

'Filtering on this sheet, this is where I want to prompt the user to select the sheet, column no in that sheet and range automatically selecting till the used range.

```
    'Set ws = Application.InputBox("Select a Range on which you want to split", Type:=8)
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vsht.vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:AB1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr


        On Error Resume Next


        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If

        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate      

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, `vsht.vcol` should be `vcol` but the rest is unclear and I'm not even sure of the question.

Comment: what the macro does is on Sheet 'Data' in col =1,The macro will filter all the unique rows one by one and creates new sheets.

Comment: My question is how do i prompt the user to select the sheet and range from the same workbook but different worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>My question is how do i prompt the user to select the sheet and range from the same workbook but different worksheet?</sub>

You've answered your question in the commented code. I'll just make a couple of adjustments.

```
dim rng as range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the Range on the Worksheet which you want to split", Type:=8)
if not rng is nothing then
    set rng = intersect(rng.entirecolumn, rng.parent.usedrange)
    debug.print rng.address(0, 0, external:=true)
else
    debug.print "nothing selected"
end if
```

Comment: The code after the comment what has to be changed then?

Comment: Tale a few minutes to look at the revised code above vs. your own code. The differences should become obvious.